# Trying to print out using event.data getting undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get my sayHello function to print out "Test" however it is printing out undefined.  I have an object and in it is a field called firstName that is set to "Test".  What am I missing so my sayHello function alerts "Test" instead of Undefined for `event.data.firstName`. Here is my code

```
$('button.focus').click(function() {
  $('div').data("greeting","Hello world");

  alert($('div').data("greeting"));

  {
    firstName: 'Test'
  }

}, sayHello);

function sayHello(event)
{
  alert(event.data.firstName)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs for event.data

An optional object of data passed to an event method when the current executing handler is bound.

In you example you are trying to bind to function one anonymous and one named.

.click() does not support that. You need to pass the event data like below

```js
$('button.focus').click({firstName: 'Test'},sayHello );
function sayHello(event)
{
  $('div').data("greeting","Hello world");
   alert($('div').data("greeting"));
   alert(event.data.firstName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="focus">focus</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`javascript` at Question does not pass an object to the event handler. The object is within a block within event handler.

You can define object outside of event handler. Use `.on()`, pass object as second parameter to `.on()`. Call `sayHello` within event handler with `event` as parameter.

```js
var data = {
  firstName: 'Test'
};

$('button.focus').on("click", data, function(event) {
  $('div').data("greeting", "Hello world");

  alert($('div').data("greeting"));

  sayHello(event)

});

function sayHello(event) {
  alert(event.data.firstName)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="focus">click</button>
```